# Bean no muestra parametro enviado desde DTO

Tags: java, sql, netbeans, jsf, primefaces

Me encuentro programando un mini formulario, la cuestión es que tengo 2 beans usuario e instituto, el usuario se loguea e ingresa a un index donde tiene que llenar un formulario, en index quiero mostrar tanto el nombre del usuario como el instituto que se loguea ambos en un **outpuLabel** solo que el valor de instituto no me lo muestra...

> Bean Usuario

```
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import dao.usuarioDAO;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import sesion.SessionUtils;

@Named(value = "usuario")
@SessionScoped
public class usuarioDTO implements Serializable {

public String getId_usuario(){
    return id_usuario;
}

public void setId_usuario(String id_usuario) {
    this.id_usuario = id_usuario;
}

public String getUsuario() {
    return usuario;
}

public void setUsuario(String usuario) {
    this.usuario = usuario;
}

public String getContraseña() {
    return contraseña;
}

public void setContraseña(String contraseña) {
    this.contraseña = contraseña;
}

public String getId_instituto() {
    return id_instituto;
}

public void setId_instituto(String id_instituto) {
    this.id_instituto = id_instituto;
}

public String getId_rol() {
    return id_rol;
}

public void setId_rol(String id_rol) {
    this.id_rol = id_rol;
}

private String id_usuario;
private String usuario;
private String contraseña;
private String id_instituto;
private boolean loggedIn = false;
private String id_rol;

public boolean isLoggedIn() {
    return loggedIn;
}

public void setLoggedIn(boolean loggedIn) {
    this.loggedIn = loggedIn;
}
/**
 * Creates a new instance of usuario
 */
public usuarioDTO() {
}

public String inicioSesion() throws SQLException{
    boolean validar = usuarioDAO.validarSesion(usuario, contraseña);
    FacesMessage message = null;
    String username;
    institutoDTO dto = new institutoDTO();
    if(validar){
        HttpSession session = SessionUtils.getSession();
        session.setAttribute("usuario", usuario);
        username = (String)session.getAttribute("usuario");
        dto.setNombre(username);
        return "index";
    } else{
        message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN, "Error de Logueo", "Usuario o Contraseña incorrecto");
        return "login";
    }
}


public String cerrarSesion(){
    HttpSession session = (HttpSession) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSession(false);
    session.invalidate();
    loggedIn = false;
    return "login";
}
```

}

> Bean Instituto

```
package dto;

import conexion.conectar;
import javax.inject.Named;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;


@Named(value = "instituto")
@SessionScoped
public class institutoDTO implements Serializable {

/**
 * Creates a new instance of institutoDTO
 */
public institutoDTO() {
}

private String id_instituto;
private String nombre;

public String getId_instituto() {
    return id_instituto;
}

public void setId_instituto(String id_instituto) {
    this.id_instituto = id_instituto;
}

public String getNombre() { 
    return nombre;
}

/*public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}*/

public void setNombre(String user)throws SQLException{
            Connection con = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
            conectar conexion = new conectar();
            con = conexion.conectar();
            String instituto = null;
            try{
                ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT NOMBRE "
                                        + "FROM INSTITUTO "
                                        + "INNER JOIN USUARIO ON USUARIO.ID_INSTITUTO = INSTITUTO.ID_INSTITUTO "
                                        + "WHERE USUARIO = ?");
                ps.setString(1, user);
                ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

                if (rs.next()){
                    instituto = rs.getString(1);
                }   
            }catch(SQLException ex){
                System.out.println("Login error -->" + ex.getMessage());
            }
            System.out.println(""+instituto);
            nombre = instituto;             
}   
}
```

> Aquí el login .xhtml

```
<h:body style="margin: 0 auto; text-align: center;">
    <p:growl id="mensajes" showDetail="true" life="2000" />
    <h:form>
    <p:panel header="Inicio de Sesión" style="position: relative; width: 25%; border-width: 2px; margin: 0 auto; text-align: center;">
            <p:panelGrid style="margin: 0 auto; text-align: center; width: 25%; margin-bottom: 0;">
                <p:row>   
                    <p:column>
                        <p:inputText required="true"
                                     requiredMessage="Por favor ingresar usuario"
                                     placeholder="Usuario"
                                     value="#{usuario.usuario}"> </p:inputText>
                    </p:column>
                </p:row>

                <p:row>
                    <p:column>
                        <p:password required="true"
                                    validatorMessage="Contraseña incorrecta"
                                    placeholder="Contraseña"
                                    value="#{usuario.contraseña}"></p:password>
                    </p:column>
                </p:row>
            </p:panelGrid>
            <f:facet name="footer" >
                <div align="center">
                    <p:commandButton value="Acceder&#187;"
                                     action="#{usuario.inicioSesion()}">
                    </p:commandButton>    
                </div>
            </f:facet>
        </p:panel>
        </h:form>
</h:body>
```

> Código del index.xhtml

```
<p:toolbar style="background: #004a93; color: #f5f5f5;">
        <f:facet name="left">
                        Bienvenido: <p:outputLabel value="#{usuario.usuario}"></p:outputLabel>
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        Instituto: <p:outputLabel value="#{instituto.nombre}"></p:outputLabel>
        </f:facet>
        <f:facet name="right">
                        <h:commandLink value="Cerrar Sesión"
                                       style="background: #004a93; color: #f5f5f5;"
                                       action="#{usuario.cerrarSesion()}"></h:commandLink>
        </f:facet>
    </p:toolbar>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> institutoDTO dto = new institutoDTO();

Los *managed beans* deben ser creados y gestionados por el framework que los controla (en este caso CDI); los beans que instancies por tu cuenta sencillamente estarán fuera del control del framework.

Así, estás creando una instancia de `institutoDto`<sup>1</sup> a la que le asignas datos, pero esa instancia desaparece cuando sales del método. Cuando haces `#{institutoDto}` estás accediendo a una instancia gestionada por CDI, diferente<sup>2</sup>.

Si necesitas una instancia gestionada desde otra instancia gestionada, basta con pedirle al framework que la inyecte; por ejemplo:

```
public class usuarioDTO implements Serializable {

   @Inject
   private institutoDto instituto;

   ...
}
```

Hay más formas y tiene sus reglas y y restricciones, aconsejo que repases algún tutorial.

Como nota final, recomiendo que en general hagas los *setters* y *getters* de los beans lo más "tontos" posibles; aparte de alguna validación (y cuando se pueda, usa `javax.validation` en vez de código) no metas lógica. Puedes añadir a los beans lógica mediante métodos que no sean *setters* ni *getters* (por ejemplo, un método `cargarDatos`). Los *getters* y los *setters* son llamados automáticamente al procesar los JSFs, cuanta más lógica tengas allí más tardará.

Además, hacer a los beans "tontos" y dejar que la lógica esté en clases separadas facilita la reutilización de código, ya que así tus beans no dependen de otras capas (por ejemplo SQL).

---

<sup>1</sup>Nota: Estaría bien que revisaras las guías de nomenclatura de Java (por ejemplo, los nombres de las clases empiezan por mayúscula). Una vez que te has acostumbrado (y el 99% de los programadores se acostumbran) se hace muy raro leer código que no sigue las normas.

<sup>2</sup>Puedes comprobarlo metiendo un log en el constructor de `institutoDto`, por ejemplo.

Comment: Gracias @SJuan efectivamente, tu comentario me ayudo, voy a documentarme más sobre el CDI  y separar la lógica de los setters y getters como me aconsejas